# Vanishing Point for my 3D engine

Tags: 3d, lua

I've been scripting a simple graphics engine in Lua based language and I realized that my 3D models had no vanishing point. Is there some sort of algorithm/equations for creating a vanishing point?

This is what my graphics engine looks like as of right now:
[graphics engine gif](https://i.gyazo.com/10d428b71c424d0ccb43da2171f40300.gif)

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your 3D models, it's about projection matrix.

Typically geometry transformed by set of matrices - world matrix that positions object in virtual world, view matrix that positions virtual camera in world, and projection matrix that takes 3d coordinates in camera view and maps it to 2d screen. You need to change that last matrix, projection matrix.

Looks like at the moment you're using orthographic projection. Check manuals for your engine on how to set camera to 'perspective' mode.

Comment: Nonono, this is entirely from scratch. And of course this isn't about my 3D models. I just want to know a way to properly draw them with a vanishing point.

Comment: How do you get 2d coordinates for 3d points? You have to multiply it by some matrix, and that matrix should be 'perspective' matrix to get effect you want.